# Make my toggle-input-source shortcut always toggle input source

Tags: macos

If there are only two input sources and the next-input-source shortcut is cmd alt space, then

1. cmd space to open spotlight
2. cmd alt space to toggle input source
3. cmd alt space to toggle input source
4. cmd space to close spotlight

The second not the original input source is now selected. It should be the first.

This is almost definitely a bug because this doesn't happen with the original ctrl alt space next-input-source shortcut.

However, is there a way to keep this keyboard shortcut and make it work correctly every time?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a shortcut to select the previous or next input source (which will do the same thing if there are only two) in **System Preferences**.

Go to **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Input Sources** and enter a shortcut there